# Every hypersurface is orientable?

Tags: differential-topology

I think that every hypersurface is orientable.

Suppose I have a hypersurface $X$ that sits inside the ambient Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Then for every $x \in X, T_x(X)$ is an $n - 1$ dimensional vector space. Hence, we can find a normal vector to the vector space. We can simply do a similar procedure to the boundary orientation where we define the orientation of a basis of $T_x(X), \{v_1, \ldots, v_{n - 1}\},$ as just the orientation of $\{n_x, v_1, \ldots, v_{n - 1}\},$ where $n_x$ is a normal vector to the vector space. I doubt this is correct but I fail to see where this falls apart.

Comment: Moebius strip sits inside the three spaces though

Comment: As far as I know, Klein bottle is a 2-dimensional manifold that doesn't embed in $R^3$. If a surface embeds as a hypersurface, then the proof seems legit.

Comment: the pointwise orientation you choose in this way may not be smooth (e.g. moebius strip)

Comment: If $X$ is a *closed* smooth hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $X$ is orientable.

Comment: Sorry for being silly but isn't the Mobius strip a compact hypersurface? So in particular it is closed? Also I thought compact hypersurfaces were orientable...

Comment: "Closed" in this context is being used in the manifold sense, not in the topology sense of "a closed subset is a subset whose complement is open".  A manifold is defined to be "closed" if it is compact and its manifold boundary is empty. In this sense the Möbius strip is most certainly *not* closed, because its manifold boundary is a circle.

Answer (score 2):

As people have pointed out above in the comments, you crucially need $X \subset \Bbb R^n$ to be closed (i.e., a compact manifold without boundary) hypersurface.

In that case, consider the restriction $\underline{\Bbb R}^n = T\Bbb R^n|_X$ of the tangent bundle to the ambient Euclidean space to $X$. $TX \subset \underline{\Bbb R}^n$ is a subbundle of codimension $1$, so we take it's orthogonal complement $NX$, which is the normal bundle of the submanifold. For your procedure to be coherent, you want a smooth section of the $1$-dimensional line bundle $NX$, which would be the family of normals $\{n_x\}_{x \in X}$ you describe.

Let $N_1 X = \{(x, v) \in NX : \|v\| = 1\}$ be the unit normal bundle; as $NX$ has rank $1$, this is a $S^0$-bundle on $X$ which is the same thing as a double cover on $X$. If this double cover wasn't trivial, there would be an embedded loop $\gamma$ in $X$ based at some point $x$ which lifts to a nontrivial embedded path $\tilde{\gamma}$ by the covering projection $N_1 X \to X$, in the sense that $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = y_0$ and $\tilde{\gamma}(1) = y_1$ where $\pi^{-1}(x) = \{y_0, y_1\}$. Let $\sigma$ be the segment in the fiber of the normal projection $NX \to X$ over $x$ joining $y_0$ and $y_1$. Then $C = \tilde{\gamma} \cup \sigma$ is a closed embedded loop in $NX$ which intersects $X$ transversely at a single point. By the tubular neighborhood theorem, we can embed $NX$ as an open neighborhood of $X$ in $\Bbb R^n$.

This would give a $1$-dimensional submanifold $C$ and a codimension $1$ submanifold $X$ in $\Bbb R^n$ with mod $2$ intersection number $1$. But $\Bbb R^n$ is simply connected, so $C$ is nullhomotopic, which is a contradiction as that would force the mod $2$ intersection number of $C$ and $X$ to be $0$.

Therefore, $N_1 X \to X$ is the trivial cover. In particular it admits a global section $n : X \to N_1 X$. $n(x)$ is a unit normal to $X$ at $x$ by construction, so this is the desired smooth family of normals to $X$ that you wanted. Now simply orient $T_x X$ according to the orientation of $T_x \Bbb R^n$ and the normal vector $n(x)$ by the "right-hand rule", following your idea.

Comment: I think the statement is true even if we drop the compactness assumption on $X$ but require that it be boundaryless and embedded properly in $\mathbb R^n$ (i.e. as a closed subset). Sketch: associated to such an $X$, we can define a real line bundle $V$ on $\mathbb R^n$ which restricts on $X$ to $NX$ - using the real analogue of the usual way to go from a (smooth) divisor to line bundle in complex/algebraic geometry. Now, $V$ is trivial since $\mathbb R^n$ is contractible and so, $NX$ is too.

Comment: @MohanSwaminathan That rings true to my ears; I like your sketch. I think it's possible to carry out the same proof idea as above: $NX$ can be embedded in $\Bbb R^n$ (we'll have varying normal radii) so the same construction above would give a loop $C$ intersecting $X$ transversely at a point. Take a big closed ball $B$ in which a nullhomotopy of $C$ fits in so that $F : C \times I \to \Bbb R^n$ is a nullhomotopy transverse to the compact submanifold with boundary $B \cap X$ which doesn't intersect $\partial(B \cap X)$. Usual transversality theory pushes through for a contradiction.

Comment: Alternatively, one could be more abstract: Take a large ball $B$ and consider the image of $X$ under $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n/B^c = S^n$. That's an embedded pseudomanifold, let's call it $Y$, in $S^n$ which gives a fundamental class $[Y] \in H_{n-1}(S^n)$ and similarly $[C] \in H_1(S^n)$. $\text{PD}[Y] \smile \text{PD}[C] = 1$ since $C$ and $Y$ intersect transversely at a point, but $[C] = 0$, contradiction (We collapsed a large ball complement instead of taking a one-point compactification since set of ends of $X$ may be badly behaved, so the notion of fundamental class of $X^+$ may get murky)

Comment: To pull the biggest nuke of all, one can dispense with the normal bundle altogether. By Alexander duality, $\tilde{H}_0(S^n \setminus Y) \cong H^{n-1}(Y)$. The above arguments really say $S^n \setminus Y$ is disconnected (if not, you can find a loop $C$ intersecting the top stratum of $Y$ transversely at a point, contradiction) so $H^{n-1}(Y) = \Bbb Z$. But $Y$ is $X/(X - K)$ where $K$ is a large compact set in $X$, so $H^{n-1}(X, X - K) \cong \Bbb Z$. Taking a direct limit over $K$, $H_c^{n-1}(X) \cong \Bbb Z$, so $X$ is orientable. I guess the takeaway is we can even drop smoothness.

Comment: Very nice! The argument in my sketch seems to be limited to $C^\infty$ submanifolds (it doesn't seem to extend to the case of $C^k$ submanifolds for $k<\infty$ in any obvious way, let alone locally flat submanifolds as your last comment does).